# I am trying to use streams in Java8.Trying to convert a for loop for iterating a list(existing code to a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Below is a for loop used for iterating requests and thereby performing some logic(getting/setting and performing null checks).

```
for (Request request : requests) {


        if (request != null && request.getProfileId() != null && 0 < request.getProfileId().longValue()) {


                Detail profileInfo=profileServiceHelper.retreieveProfile(request.getProfileId());

                if (profileInfo != null) {
                    Info info=requestMapper.mapLiloProfileDetail(profileInfo, request);

                    if (info!= null) {
                        profiles.add(info);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I m trying to convert the above for loop to a stream:
so far what i have done is (created a stream , used filter and map)

```
requests.stream()
    .filter(request->request != null && request.getProfileId() != null && 0 < request.getProfileId().longValue())
    .map(request -> profileServiceHelper.retreieveProfile(request.getProfileId()));
        //.map((profileDetail,request)->(profileDetail!=null)?requestMapper.mapLiloProfileDetail(profileDetail, request):"");
```

I need to pass a function with two params in the map method of stream.

Please help out

Comment: Please start by editing your question into something more readable.

Comment: edited my code!

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts.

Comment: @Hali did any of the answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Going back to a previous value carried in a stream is always an issue. Here is a workaround that works by removing the need to call `Stream#filter` for null-checking.

An alternate option for expression-style null-checking is to use the new Java 8 `Optional#ofNullable` and `Optional#map` static methods. This even allows us to embed all of the null-checking and mapping into a `forEach`, which means we can refer back to the original `request`!

```
requests.forEach(r -> Optional.ofNullable(r)
        .map(Request::getProfileId).map(id -> profileServiceHelper::retrieveProfile)
        .map(d -> requestMapper.mapLiloProfileDetail(d, r)).ifPresent(profiles::add));
```

One more change I made to the sequence of things is that this last statement splits `getProfileId` and `profileServiceHelper.retrieveProfile` into two separate steps. This makes it slightly more readable and allows for a method reference.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Stream objects do not allow you to access values of the previous step in any of the subsequent steps - each step in stream processing is implied to be "its own thing", and ideally it should also depend only on step inputs.

But going back to question at hand, here is how it can be solved:

```
requests.stream()
  .filter(Objects::nonNull) // you might actually want to review if there can be a null there, looks very awkward if they can
  .filter(request -> request.getProfileId() != null && 0 < request.getProfileId())
  .flatMap(request -> {
     Detail profileInfo = profileServiceHelper.retrieveProfileInfo(request.getProfileId());
     if (profileInfo != null) {
       return Stream.of(requestMapper.mapLiloProfileDetail(profileInfo, request));
     }
     else return Stream.empty();
   })
   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
   .forEach(profiles::add);
```

Do note, however, that Java8's lambdas and method references are not be-all end-all, and there usually is very little need for converting code that works perfectly fine into streams and lambdas.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
    Predicate<Request> filter = req -> req != null && req.getProfileId() != null && 0 < req.getProfileId().longValue() && profileServiceHelper.retreieveProfile(req.getProfileId()) != null && requestMapper.mapLiloProfileDetail(profileInfo, req) != null;
    requests.stream().filter(filter).forEach(req -> profiles.add(requestMapper.mapLiloProfileDetail(profileServiceHelper.retreieveProfile(req.getProfileId()), req)));
```

Comment: I got it ...the above code worked file...but i want to real ways of using lambda in everyday code or rather refracting existing code to java8. I generraly have methods like mapOneObjectToAnother which takes one and transforms to another .

Comment: revClassTO = new  com.wdw.folio.service.transferobject.RevenueClassificationTO();
            revClassTO.setName(classificationVO.getName());
            revClassTO.setRevenueClassificationID(Long.valueOf(classificationVO.getId()));

Comment: I want to know in which scenrios are lambdas useful except streams

Comment: In that case go through online lambdas and streams tutorials :). Like [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTa9YGfyhyW2CqdtW9RtY-I3)